# Typescript set type annotation of JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How would I set a type annotation of JSX?

I want to check if props received are type of JSX and not any other type.

This is what my interface looks like:

```
interface ITextEditorProps{
  value: any
}

// Component 
<TextEditor value={<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>} />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a type `JSX.Element` for a broader approach or directly with `React.ReactElement<type>`

```
interface ITextEditorProps {
    value: JSX.Element // React.ReactElement<type> also possible
}
```

Comment: It depends on how strict you want to be with your typing. It can be JSX.Element (that is type which extends ReactElement). And if you want to have kinda loose typing then you can use ReactNode. It adds primitives to possible values